# Is there anything I can do about all the open windows when I open a VB6 project?

Tags: vb6

Whenever I open the VB6 project I am converting to VB.NET, the IDE has a myriad open windows. Apart from tiling them for quick access to the close buttons and closing them all one by one, is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Press and hold `Ctrl+F4`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add the [MZ Toolkit](http://www.mztools.com/index.aspx) to your VB6 IDE, that includes a "close all windows" button (along with numerous other handy things).

Comment: Thank you. Anything to improve that godawful IDE will be great. Thank goodness I'm only reading code in it, not writing it!

Answer (score 6):

First close all the code windows in the VB6 IDE, then exit the IDE. Go to the folder where the VB6 project is and find the file with the .vbw file extension. Mark that file as read-only. This will prevent the IDE from saving the window configurations when you exit the IDE in the future.

Comment: Deleting the vbw file will also stop it opening them again the next time it's started.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the .vbw file extension had it's read-only attribute bit set.  I cleared the forms are now saved correctly.